# Create a document library in a sharepoint online site with python

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, script, microsoft-graph, python

I am trying to create a document library with a python script.

I have tried doing it using Microsoft graph but I am having trouble doing with POST request and I didn't succeed.

I also tried doing so with the new O365 library but the library doesn't have any documentation so I've had trouble working with this library.

Anyway I would like some help with this, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a try below python script:

```
from config import config
from shareplum import Site
from shareplum import Office365
from shareplum.site import Version

# get data from configuration
username = config['sp_user']
password = config['sp_password']

authcookie = Office365('https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com', username=username, password=password).GetCookies()

site = Site('https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/sbdev/subtest01',version=Version.v365, authcookie=authcookie)

newlist=site.AddList('My New List', description='Great List!', template_id='Document Library')

print(newlist)
```

The above refer to ['shareplum' library](https://shareplum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#access-rest-api). And you can check the full code here:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/sharedproject/blob/master/PythonConsole-uploadfileSPO/PythonApplication2/addDocLib.py

BR